# Add complex north arrow to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, north-arrow

[image]

How do you add this type of north arrow to ArcMap?

Comment: Do you have that north arrow available to add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an image of your North Arrow available, the following steps should help you load it into your map.

(I found a similar arrow on Google Images, so I saved that and set the background as transparent)

1. In ArcMap on the layout view select *Insert* > *North Arrow*
   [image]
2. Click *Properties*
   [image]
3. Click *Symbol*
   [image]
4. Click *Edit Symbol*
   [image]
5. Select *Picture Marker Symbol* and browse to your image
   [image]
6. Set the size of your North Arrow
   [image]
7. OK all the way back to your map

You should now see your north arrow on your layout, ready to be positioned and sized as required.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have an image of the north arrow you want, step through this series of clicks (starting in Layout View):

1. Insert (the menu button at the top of ArcMap)
2. North Arrow
3. Properties
4. Symbol
5. Edit Symbol
6. In the Type drop-down, select "Picture marker symbol"
7. Navigate to your image

ArcMap will assume that the top of your image is North, and it will rotate the image accordingly if your data frame has an alternative orientation.