# Adding bearing compass to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, compass

I need to add a bearing compass to ArcMap 10.3.1. I can't seem to find the steps or process to do so.

I am trying to add a compass with a 360° bearing, centring on top of a lookout in ArcMap. I can't seem to find the steps or process to do so. 
There will be multiple compasses that will be used to cross reference bearings from each lookout.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Can you please [edit] your question to add a bit more detail about what you're trying to do, perhaps including a screenshot?

Comment: Do you mean something like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203831/add-complex-north-arrow-to-arcmap/203837#203837

Answer (score 2):

I draw mine in Adobe Illustrator, then export to EMF. Sometimes i use 2 superimposed graphics, one for compass, one for arrow, so i can rotate the arrow. [image]